# How to manage repeating UI elements

Tags: java, android, user-interface

How do you avoid repeating code for UI elements that are exactly the same? In android, to access an element programatically you need to name each element with a unique id.

For example I have a back button that performs the exact same function wherever its used but because of having to id them, I end up having BackButton1, BackButton2, BackButton3 etc. As a result I have to rewrite the same OnClickListener for each button.

Is there something similar to a html 'class' attribute or a similar way to group elements in android? If not, what is the best way to name repeating elements?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are defining the button in the layout xml, then you can use the `onclick` attribute to refer to a common method in your activity that will called when the button is clicked.

if you use `onclick="doBack"` in the xml in then your activity you have a method called

```
public void doBack(View v) {
   // perform back
}
```

Comment: This was a suitable fix to my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can reuse your UI components, see [Android Developer's site](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) for more details:

There are `ViewStub`'s too to do what you want, incase you do not want the entire `Layout` to be included but just some components and again the best source to learn this will be [Android developers website](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-stubs.html)

As far as reusing `ID`'s is concerned, my take is you can reuse ID's as long as they are not in the same `Activity`

From dev document:

> An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be
>   unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often
>   be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when
>   possible).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the fact that having multiple elements on a single user-interface that do the same exact thing is a bad idea? If you have a button which on being clicked takes you to the previous activity, you should probably have it in a single easily accessible part of the screen.